# Problem on Exporting SSRS reports to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

While exporting my ssrs report to excel,i am getting that report with white background in excel sheet instead of displaying those data within the gridlines.How can i do this?

Please help me to get a solution for this!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the Border options in the properties dialog for your report objects. Don't forget to set the Border Colour, Border Style *and* Border Width properties - if you have the Colour set to black and the Width set to 1pt, but the Style set to none, you won't see any borders around your cells.

Comment: Yeah..After setting borders to the cells of a table in ssrs report,i can view the borders only for that particular table while exporting that report to excel.The rest of the cells in the Excel sheet remains with white background only.I just want to display the entire excel sheet with gridlines.Is there any provision to do this?

Comment: I don't know of any within SSRS, although it's easy enough in Excel - just click the top left hand corner of the sheet to select all cells, then select the All Borders option from the Borders menu.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add another solution in case anyone else has a mostly-white Excel worksheet (with no visible gridlines).  What I mean is that cell IV65536 had no visible border. The solution is really simple:

```
1) go to the View ribbon
2) find the Show group
3) put a check in the box for "Gridlines"
```

For some reason, the SSRS default is to uncheck the "Gridlines" box.